# Is html title attribute a toolip?

Tags: html

I have question to know the truth. can some one tell me is HTML `title` attribute a tool tip.
Someone told me it is not a tooltip.
Can anybody describe what is a tool tip?
and HTML title is it or not?
I need the truth pleas.

Answer (score 1):

It is "Advisory information for the element" according to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#attributes-1).

Some browsers render it as a tooltip when you hover the element.

Obviously a screen reader would not, it reads it out.

A touch screen browser would not, it doesn't support a hover state.

Answer (score 0):

Html title attribute is not a tool tip. But browsers can display it as a tooltip.

The problem with this is that you no longer control what your website shows. You will depend on whether the browser wants to show it or not.
A tooltip is programmed so you can control the operation, and you can change it, add events, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_title.asp

"The title attribute is part of the Global Attributes, and can be used on any HTML element."

It is simply an attribute, and the value of this attribute is being shown by most browsers when hovering over the element looking like a tool tip.

In my opinion, it actually is a tooltip, since the value of the attribute is shown when the user hovers his mouse over the element. But the styling and even if the value is being shown is up to the browser, and you have no control over it.

It just depends on what is a tooltip for you personally :) 
Usually, "web people" refer to tooltips as popup content when hovering over an element. Usually, these tooltips are being shown using JavaScript or vanilly CSS.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp

My 2 cents - but I think it's really up to one personally whether you think of it as a tooltip.

Answer (score -1):

Html title attribute is not tool-tip but on hover of the element we can see the title the element

For Eg:

ABCD INFO

so we will get output as

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9S0i.png)